# How to view observable states in Corda

Tags: corda

I have been following the official tutorials on how to implement observer nodes from [here](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-observer-nodes.html) and [here](https://www.corda.net/2017/12/observer-nodes/). I tried testing the flow to broadcast the transaction to observer nodes, however, I am not sure if I implemented the flow correctly. After running the flow, no states showed up in the vault of the observer node. No states (that corresponded to the transaction that was broadcast) showed up when I ran a RPC vault query nor did it show when I accessed the H2 database of the observer node. Debugging showed that the flow code was called. No exception was thrown as well.

Is the flow working correctly? Also how can I view the broadcasted transactions as an observer node - is it stored as a consumed state in its vault?

The flow code:

```
object BroadcastTransaction {

@InitiatingFlow
class BroadcastTransactionToObservers(private val stx: SignedTransaction, private val observers: List<Party>) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val sessions = observers.map { initiateFlow(it) }

        sessions.forEach { subFlow(SendTransactionFlow(it, stx)) }
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(BroadcastTransactionToObservers::class)
class RecordTransactionAsObserver(private val otherSession: FlowSession) :FlowLogic<Unit>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        subFlow( ReceiveTransactionFlow(
                otherSideSession = otherSession,
                checkSufficientSignatures = true,
                statesToRecord = StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE
            )
        )
    }
}
```

}

How I call the flow:

```
subFlow(BroadcastTransaction.BroadcastTransactionToObservers(fullySignedTx, listOf(observer)))
```

Prior initiating flow:

```
    @InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class Initiator (val id: String,
                 val transferParty : Party,
                val observer : Party) : BaseFlow() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() : SignedTransaction {

        progressTracker.currentStep = ID_OTHER_NODES
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]

        progressTracker.currentStep = EXTRACTING_VAULT_STATES
        val stateAndRef = getItemStateByItemId(id)
        val inputState = stateAndRef.state.data 

        progressTracker.currentStep = TX_BUILDING
        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary)
        val outputState = createOutput(inputState)  

        val signerKeys = listOf(ourIdentity.owningKey, transferParty.owningKey)

        val cmd = Command(outputState.command, signerKeys) 

        txBuilder.addInputState(stateAndRef)
                .addOutputState(outputState.ownableState, CONTRACT_ID)
                .addCommand(cmd)

        progressTracker.currentStep = TX_VERIFICATION
        txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

        progressTracker.currentStep = TX_SIGNING
        val signedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

        progressTracker.currentStep = SENDING_AND_RECEIVING_DATA

        val sessions = setOf(initiateFlow(transferParty))
        progressTracker.currentStep = SIGS_GATHERING
        val fullySignedTx: SignedTransaction = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(signedTx, sessions, SIGS_GATHERING.childProgressTracker()))
        subFlow(BroadcastTransaction.BroadcastTransactionToObservers(fullySignedTx, listOf(observer)))

        progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISATION
        return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, setOf(ourIdentity),FINALISATION.childProgressTracker()))



    }
```

Comment: This looks ok. Could you possibly provide the code to take a look? Also, is the observer recording the transaction twice (once as a non-observer and once as an observer)?

Comment: I just added some more code, and no the observer does not record the transaction twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are broadcasting the transaction to the observer before it has received a signature from the notary as part of `FinalityFlow`. Nodes will not record a transaction's states in their vault unless it has all the required signatures, including the notary's.

Try moving the call to `FinalityFlow` above the call to `BroadcastTransaction.BroadcastTransactionToObservers`.